# Fail to add TextView marquee effect in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a ListView with its TextView as follow. Some text in the ListView are too long so I want to make them scroll horizontally.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/food_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_background" />
```

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/food_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Inside my `addTextChangedListener`, I have the following code (the list will change when searching in an EditText accorindly). However the
Each TextView item inside the ListView is just in one line, but does not scroll horizontally. Using `System.out.println(foodName.getText())` I can get all item names within the ListView, so is there anything wrong with `foodNameText.setSelected(true);`, when using in the for loop?

```
myListAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(AddNewFoodActivity.this, foodListArray, R.layout.food_list_view, colHEAD, dataCell);
                                        foodList.setAdapter(myListAdapter);

int count = foodList.getAdapter().getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    TextView foodNameText = (TextView) foodList.getAdapter().getView(i, null, 
                         foodList).findViewById(R.id.food_item);
    foodNameText.setSelected(true);                                      
    //System.out.println(foodName.getText());
}
```

Comment: -set foodNameText.setSelected(true); this line into your adapter this will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:text="Your text" />


foodNameText.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
foodNameText.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
foodNameText.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
foodNameText.setFocusable(true);
foodNameText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```